# How to display the result of Lucene indexsearcher pagewise in JSP

Tags: jsp, lucene, pagination

I have built a web interface in JSP where user can type her query and the interface records the user's query along with her present location and these are passed to a Lucene index searcher SearchDB as parameters. Now I want to display the result of the search pagewise back in same JSP. The code of JSP and Lucene index searcher, that I have written taking the help of the other posts, are as follows:

result.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.util.*,java.io.*,parser.SearchDB,org.apache.lucene.analysis.*" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <%! String myQuery; String city; String latitude; String longitude; %>
  <%
      myQuery=request.getParameter("myQuery");
      city=request.getParameter("city");
      latitude=request.getParameter("latitude");
      longitude=request.getParameter("longitude");
      Cookie cookies [] = request.getCookies();
      Cookie myCity=null;
      Cookie myLat=null;
      Cookie myLong=null;
      if(city!=null)
       {
         myCity=new Cookie("city",city);
         myCity.setMaxAge(365*24*60*60);
         response.addCookie(myCity);
         myLat=new Cookie("latitude",latitude);
         myLat.setMaxAge(365*24*60*60);
         response.addCookie(myLat);
         myLong=new Cookie("longitude",longitude);
         myLong.setMaxAge(365*24*60*60);
         response.addCookie(myLong);
       }
    else
       { 
         for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) 
         {   
               if (cookies[i].getName().equals("city"))
                  {
                    myCity=cookies[i];
                    city=myCity.getValue();
                  }
              else
                if(cookies[i].getName().equals("latitude"))
                 {
                      myLat=cookies[i];
                      latitude=myLat.getValue();
                 }
                else
                  if(cookies[i].getName().equals("longitude"))
                   {
                       myLong=cookies[i];
                       longitude=myLong.getValue();
                   }
             }
    }
  SearchDB s = new SearchDB();
  System.out.println("Query="+myQuery+" and City="+city);
  s.searchdb(myQuery, city);
%>

 <form name="frm" method="post" action="result.jsp">
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
   <td width="22%">&nbsp;</td>
   <td width="78%">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>&nbsp; </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="myQuery" placeholder="Type here"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </form>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <p>Query phrase is : <%=myQuery%></p>
   <p>User's city : <%=city%></p>
   <p>User's latitude : <%=latitude%></p>
   <p>User's longitude : <%=longitude%></p>
   </body>
  </html>
```

SearchDB.java

```
package parser;


public class SearchDB {

public void searchdb(String myQuery, String myCity) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Searching in the database ...");
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT);

    QueryParser cityQP = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "city", analyzer);
    Query cityQuery = cityQP.parse(myCity);

    QueryParser titleQP = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "title", analyzer);
    Query titleQuery = titleQP.parse(myQuery);

    BooleanQuery finalQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    finalQuery.add(cityQuery, Occur.MUST); must occur.
    finalQuery.add(titleQuery, Occur.MUST); 

    System.out.println("Final Query="+finalQuery.toString());

    Directory dir=FSDirectory.open(new File(path of index directory"));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir, true);
    TopDocs hits = searcher.search(finalQuery, 20);

    System.out.println("Number of hits="+hits.totalHits);
    for(ScoreDoc match : hits.scoreDocs)
    { 
       System.out.println(searcher.doc(match.doc).get("title")+" with score="+match.score);
       System.out.println("_______");
    }
    searcher.close();
    dir.close();
}
```

}

I am new to both Lucene and JSP. I don't have any idea what changes should be done to the above JAVA and JSP code so that the results are displayed pagwise. So any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: 1) How many results per query are possible at most: 10s / 100s / or thousands? 2) are you familiar with front-end like javascript, ajax?

Comment: Results per query can be at most 100s. I have done little bit coding in Javascript but I am not familiar with Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the last ScoreDoc obtained to [IndexSearcher.searchAfter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#searchAfter%28org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int%29), to get the next set of documents.  So, the value of match after youu've completed the for loop should be the ScoreDoc to pass to SearchAfter.

Such as:

```
TopDocs hits = searcher.search(finalQuery, 20);
System.out.println("Number of hits="+hits.totalHits);

while(not done paging...) {
    ScoreDoc last;
    for(ScoreDoc match : hits.scoreDocs)
    { 
        System.out.println(searcher.doc(match.doc).get("title")+" with score="+match.score);
        System.out.println("_______");
        last = match;
    }
    hits = searcher.searchAfter(last, finalQuery, 20);
}
```

Comment: You have told how to page the results of Lucene but I want to know  also how to display them as pagewise manner like Google or any standard search engine in JSP.